# Error when trying to use <lightning:inputRichText> in place of <ui:inputRichText>

Tags: lightning-aura-components

The answer to a previous question got me looking and the aura git repo and I see this under the `ui` component:

> We recommend that you use `<code>lightning:inputRichText</code>` instead of `<code>ui:inputRichText</code>`. `<code>ui:inputRichText</code>` is no longer supported when LockerService is activated.

However whenever I try to use `<lightning:inputRichText>` in v40.0 I get the following error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Assertion Failed!: Failed to find definition for dependency: lightning-icon : undefined Failing descriptor: {lightning:inputRichText}

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page id="myTestPage" showHeader="false" sideBar="false" standardStylesheets="false">


    <apex:includeLightning/>
    <apex:slds />


    <script>

        $Lightning.use("c:myTestApp", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                    "c:myTestComp",
                    {},
                    "component_content",
                    function (cmp) {
                        var loadingDivElt = document.getElementById("loader");
                        loadingDivElt.style.display = 'none';
                    });
        });

    </script>

    <div class="slds-scoped">
        <div id="loader" class="slds-grid slds-grid--frame">
            <div class="slds-spinner_container">
                <div class="slds-spinner slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner--large" role="alert">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="component_content">
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

**Lightning App**

```
<aura:application description="myTestApp" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:myTestComp"/>
</aura:application>
```

**Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component description="myTestComp">
    <aura:attribute name="enteredText" type="String"/>
    <lightning:inputRichText placeholder="Enter Some Text" value="{!v.enteredText}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Is something I am doing incorrect? `<ui>` still works (even on v40.0 which is locker). Maybe `<lightning:inputRichText>` cannot be used with `ltng:outApp`?

Comment: You're not alone, although I'm also finding that ui:inputRichText renders, although doesn't update its bound value attribute.

Comment: @RobBaillie well crap. Can you get the value from the rich text input with v.value? Or is it essentially useless. Guess I need to do some tests.

Comment: I have to admit that I haven't tried, as using the rich text component was opportunistic for us.  As soon as we found it didn't immediately work we implemented a different solution (plain old text area).

Comment: @RobBaillie - Yup. Just tried. cannot access the value of the UI input and it does not seem to update and value provider either. Went with a `textarea` component.